# Pugixml node line number

Tags: pugixml

Is it possible to get line number from xml_node in pugixml?

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <test />
</resources>
```

It should return '3' for "test".

Comment: You can use node.offset_debug and code from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003471/convert-pugixmls-result-offset-to-column-line